# How to automatically answer defaults when running outlook 2013 for first time

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

Is there a way to automatically use/accept the defaults when running Outlook 2013 for the first time on a profile? We have to re-set Outlook to First-Run status on several computers/windows profiles. 
We don't want the users to have to do the initial setup again (it will cause too many questions) and we use the defaults anyway.

Thanks,
Travis

Comment: Have you tried looking at prepackaging default options for Office using an MST?

Comment: You want to create email profile or configure Outlook options?